# react native: how to make two images fade to each other?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to have two images that after time fade into another.

So far my idea was to make one cover the other and change its transparency via time or animation function. I didn't succeed in formatting the images to overlap.

Is there a better way? And how do I make them overlap?

Comment: Can you provide the two images?

Answer (score 3):

```
<Image style={{position:'absolute'}} />
<Image />
```

Setting the first Image's position with 'absolute' can make them overlap.

And here is the demo:

```
getInitialState: function (){
  return {
    fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0),
  };
},
componentDidMount: function() {
  Animated.timing(          
    this.state.fadeAnim,    
    {
      toValue: 1,
      duration:1000
    },
  ).start();                
},
render: function() {
  <View style={{flex:1}}>
    <Animated.Image source={require('image!image1')} style={{width:320,height:320,resizeMode:'cover',position:'absolute'}}  />
    <Animated.Image source={require('image!image2')} style={{width:320,height:320,resizeMode:'cover',opacity:this.state.fadeAnim}}  />
  </View>
}
```